# Monad Stack and modifying reader environment

Tags: haskell

```
type InterpreterMonad = StateT (MEMORY, FUNCTIONS) (ReaderT (NameAddress, NameAddress) (ErrorT String  IO))
interpreteStmt :: Stmt -> InterpreterMonad ()


handleFCall :: VarName -> [CallArg] -> InterpreterMonad ()
handleFCall (VarName name) argsCall =  do
    (memory, functions) <- get
    case (Map.lookup (VarName name) functions) of
        Nothing -> throwError $ "error"
        (Just ((DefFun  varname argsDef typ begin statements end), env)) -> (checkCoherenceTypesArgs varname argsDef argsCall) >>= \_ -> argsToContext argsDef argsCall env >>= \_ -> interpreter statements >>= \_ -> return ()
```

I don't put whole code to make my problem clearer.
And now, I would like to modify Reader monad ( I mean environment in Reader) in `handleFCall` Function for `interpreter statements`. How to do it?

P.S. My attempt: ( It doesn't work, please explain why )

```
argsToContext :: [DefArg] -> [CallArg] -> NameAddress -> InterpreterMonad ()
argsToContext xs ys env = do
    (memory, fs) <- get
    (mem, args) <- (argsToContext' xs ys memory Map.empty)
    put ( mem, fs) 
    throwError $ "Tutej "  ++ (show args) ++ " memory " ++ (show mem)
    local (\_ -> (env, args)) ask
    return ()
```

Comment: note: `>>= \_ -> ..` is the same as `>>`, also it is advisable to stick to a line length of more or less 80 characters to make your code readable.

Comment: Also, note that `local (\_ -> ...) ask` doesn't do anything. The environment is modified just for the `ask` - after it returns the reader environment is "restored" so to speak. See my answer for an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

You use the `local` function. Here is a short example:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Except

type MyMonad = StateT String (ReaderT Int (ExceptT String IO))

foo :: Int -> MyMonad ()
foo x = do
  env <- ask
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ "x = " ++ show x ++ " and env is: " ++ show env

t1 :: MyMonad ()
t1 = do
  foo 1                        -- env = 13
  local (+20) $ foo 2          -- env = 20+13 = 33
  local (const 42) $ foo 3     -- env = 42
  foo 4                        -- env = 13

example = runExceptT (runReaderT (runStateT t1 "some state") 13)
```

Output from running `example`:

```
x = 1 and env is: 13
x = 2 and env is: 33
x = 3 and env is: 42
x = 4 and env is: 13
Right ((),"some state")
```

Initially the Reader environment is 13. The `local (+20)` call executes `foo 2` with the Reader environment set to 13+20. Then `foo 3` is executed with the Reader environment set to 42. Finally, `foo 4` is executed in the original environment.